# Looking to find (or build) a particular Python geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, query

There is a large area (a wildlife refuge) of nearly 200,00 acres that we have loads of spatial data for, from habitat management projects from the past several years. My boss (who isn't GIS savvy) would like to be able to choose a point or area within those 200,000 acres, and easily access all of the spatial data in it's vicinity, without having to navigate through an unwieldy number of layers.

I've put together a "master" mxd of all the layers, which looks like this: 
[image]

What I'm looking for is a tool whereby my boss could input a latitude and longitude coordinate of interest, and it would return all the nearby spatial data (i.e. the points/lines/polygons it falls on or are within x distance).

Would it be possible to write a Python script that would do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Capture the point, buffer it, save it as a shapefile then use select by location for all layers. If the layer Describe FID set is not empty there's a selection, then proceed to reporting. It's a bit of work but can be done as an addin.

Comment: what kind of interactivity do you expect ? Basically your boss could use the "search tool" then the "identify tool" to get information where he clicks

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thank for the input. When you say "proceed to reporting", what you you mean by that? And could those steps be automated, so that the only input needed by the user is lat/long coordinates?

Comment: @radouxju I'm looking for minimal interactivity. My boss doesn't really use ArcGIS much at all, so I'd like to have it so the only thing he needs to do is input coordinates, and the tool would return all the nearby features from various layers.

Comment: By reporting I mean open a search cursor on the selected features with fields that you are interested in and write to a text file. I can't say from here what fields are important, it's up to you to decide on a report template for each potential layer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you could create a python addin to do this for you!
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000

Basically, you would be able to create a tool that could sit in your bosses tool bar. Using the tool your boss could click the map and get the data back for the area as you described.

The tool would take care of all the spatial selection and so forth using the standard arcpy libraries and the available options with the pythonaddins module.

Here's two ways you could approach this.
First, you could use a **tool** addin (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/tool/014p0000001q000000/)which would use a set distance every time (50 meters for example) once the map is clicked.

The other way would be to also use a tool addin as above, but combine it with a combobox to have a value typed in (50 meters), which would be the distance used for the search. Both can be contained on the same toolbar and can read from one another if setup properly.

You're tool should validate the number (to ensure that it is in fact a number), then perform the selection. The python addin's can also throw a message box up if a value is wrong (if text is typed for example).

You could go above and beyond using ArcObjects, but thats probably overkill for what you're describing above. ArcObjects does have certain benefits over the python addin, but again, its far more complex to achieve the same results.
Here's a link to info about ArcObjects if you want to learn more (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/)

Comment: Feel free to send me a message if you want help at all.

Comment: If he is going to click on the map use the Identify tool and set up the Display tab labels to sort nicely.  I set their ArcMap Options to use all visible layers and they get every layer turned on.  All users (secretaries, professionals and managers) use it in ArcMap in my organization.  I'd never create a tool like this as it is recreating the wheel if the purpose was just for viewing information.  If it is a real report he wants then that is different.

Comment: If it was for a single point then the identify tool would suffice. Based on what was described above, it sounds like he wants to query a number of layers based on an XY location, then return all the selected items within the buffer. The tool isn't recreating the wheel, its functionally combining a number of tasks together into a single item for efficiency purposes.

Comment: I never use Identify for a point.  I drag a box and get everything touched (the rectangle can be a square or taller or wider, depending on my desire).  Works for me so it is recreating the wheel for me.  It is interactive (flash, remove from list, etc., just left click, hold it down and drag, then release) so better than any list you may create for an interactive query tool.  I grant that if reporting or file output is the objective then a tool needs to be built, but not for interactive querying purposes.